# Unable to print lines in a loop conditionally

Tags: python-3.x

need help on this script where I try to get output related to that command. For example, in the below code 
    "info related to process and the output should be ps -ef command output and should continue to the next command and print statement likewise"
But i get the lines saying

> info related to process and all the commands are being displayed at once.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import os
state = ['process' , 'http status' , 'date info' , 'system']
def comm(com):
    for i in state:
            for j in com:
                    print (f"info related to {i}")
                    os.system(j)

cmd = ['ps -ef | head -2' , 'systemctl status httpd' , 'date' , 'uptime']
comm(cmd)
```

OUTPUT:

```
info related to process
UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root          1      0  0 10:13 ?        00:00:19 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd - 
-switched-root --system --deserialize 22
info related to process
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-03-27 18:27:50 IST; 1 day 2h ago
 Docs: man:httpd(8)
       man:apachectl(8)
 Process: 8585 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1367 (httpd)
Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 
B/sec"
Tasks: 6
CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
       ├─1367 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       ├─8597 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       ├─8598 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       ├─8599 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       ├─8600 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
       └─8601 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

info related to process
Thu Mar 28 21:03:57 IST 2019
info related to process
21:03:57 up 10:50,  4 users,  load average: 0.35, 0.09, 0.14
```

Comment: When running your code, everything seems fine. Can you copy your output ? Also what console are you using ?

Comment: Please find the output:

Comment: The answer lies in @Etienne. Take a close look to your code. If you have any other issues , try to run ```for i in range() : for j in range() : print(i,j) ```

Answer (score 1):

You have two loops, one being nested in the other. That means anything the inner loop does will be executed in every iteration of the outer loop. That's just how loops work, but not what (I presume) you want to do here.

You have commands to be executed by the `os` module and several state names that are associated with them. From a data-first point of view we could structure them in a dictionary:

```py
commands = {
    'process': 'ps -ef',
    'http status': 'systemctl status httpd',
    'date info': 'date',
    'sytem': 'uptime',
}
```

Now when we iterate over this dictionary, in each iteration we will have both the state name and the command to be run as loop variables. The loops become a single `for` loop and we end up with:

```py
def comm(commands):
    for name, command in commands.items():
        print (f"info related to {name}")
        os.system(command)
```